# How to resolve Error 500- [object SequelizeInstance:users] mysql Authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication, sequelize.js, passport.js, jwt

am looking for help here. Any Pointers or resolution will be most appreciated.
I am building a MERN Authentication/ Authorization App and during Authentication Attempt I get this error 500 : [object SequelizeInstance:users].

I am using Passport, mysql database, and sequelize.
Here are my build details below.

Model

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("users", {
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        }
    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: async function (user) {
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                user.password = await bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
            }
        },

        instanceMethods: {
            validPassword: function (password) {
                return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) 
                        return cb(err);
                     else {
                        if (!isMatch) 
                            return cb(null, isMatch);
                        

                        return cb(null, this);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


    return User;
};
```

PassportJs

```js
const config = require("./config/auth.config");
const db = require("./models");
const User = db.user;

const cookieExtractor = req => {
    let token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies) {
        token = req.cookies["access_token"];
    }
    return token;
}

// authorization
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor,
    secretOrKey: config.secret
}, (payload, done) => {
    User.findByPk({
        id: payload.sub
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err)
            return done(err, false);



        if (user)
            return done(null, user);
        else
            return done(null, false);



    });
}));

// authenticated local strategy using username and password
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    }).then((err, user) => { // something went wrong with database
        if (err)
            return done(err);



        // if no user exist
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false);



        // check if password is correct
        user.validPassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err)
                return done(err)
            if (!isMatch)
                return done(null, false)
            return done(null, user)


        }).catch(e => done(err))
    });
}));
```

login controller

```js
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const {
        username,
        email,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        password
    } = req.body;
    User.create({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        password: password
    }).then((user) => {
        if (req.body.roles) {
            Role.findAll({
                where: {
                    name: {
                        [Op.or]: req.body.roles
                    }
                }
            }).then((roles) => {
                user.setRoles(roles).then(() => {
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: {
                            msgBody: "Account successfully created",
                            msgError: false
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        } else {
            user.setRoles([3]).then(() => {
                res.status(201).json({
                    message: {
                        msgBody: "Account successfully created",
                        msgError: false
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: {
                msgBody: err.message,
                msgError: true
            }
        });
    });
};


exports.login = (req, res) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const {
            id,
            username,

        } = req.user;
        const token = signToken(id);
        res.cookie('access_token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: true
        });
        var authorities = [];
        user.getRoles().then(roles => {
            for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                authorities.push("ROLE_" + roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
            }
        });
        res.status(200).json({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user: {
                username,
                roles: authorities
            }
        });


    } else {
        User.findOne({
                where: {
                    username: username
                }
            }),
            (err, user) => {
                if (err)
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: {
                            msgBody: "Error has occurred",
                            msgError: true
                        }
                    });


                if (user)
                    res.status(400).json({
                        message: {
                            msgBody: "Wrong password!",
                            msgError: true
                        }
                    });
                else {
                    res.status(401).json({
                        message: {
                            msgBody: "Please Register",
                            msgError: true
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
    }

}
```

route

```js
const controller = require("../controller/auth.controller");
const passport = require('passport')
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });


    app.post("/login", requireSignin, controller.login);


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this.

1. I added serializeUser and deserializeUser to my passport.js file
2. I also a new function to compare my password in my user model and subsequently updated my local strategy code in my passport.js

user model updated

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("users", {
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
        },
        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true,
        },
        resetPasswordToken: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        resetPasswordExpires: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
    });
    User.prototype.comparePassword = function comparePassword(candidatePassword, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          cb(err, isMatch);
        });
      };
    return User;
};
```

my updated passport.js

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const config = require("./config/auth.config");
const db = require("./models");
const User = db.user;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('serializing user: ', user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
  });

const cookieExtractor = (req) => {
    let token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies) {
        token = req.cookies["access_token"];
    }
    return token;
};


    

// authorization
passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy({
            jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor,
            secretOrKey: config.secret,
        },
        (payload, done) => {
            User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        id: payload.sub,
                    },
                },
                (err, user) => {
                    if (err) return done(err, false);

                    if (user) return done(null, user);
                    else return done(null, false);
                }
            );
        }
    )
);

// authenticated local strategy using username and password
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username' }, (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({
      where: { username: username},
    }).then(( user, err) => {
      if(err)
        return done(err);
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        }
        return done(null, false);
      });
    });
  }));
```